# Composable functions for Vue event handlers

Tags: vue.js

I'm using Vue 2.0, ES6, Webpack.

I have one component(let's call it `Parent`) and few children(let's call it `text-input` each). Every `text-input` emits an event called `change` and each one should alter one different property inside Parent. Let's say `Parent` has an data named `info` and inside `info` I have, name, email, etc.

What I want to accomplish is to set the right property(name, email, ...) using the same function for my `@change` option.

```
<text-input
   @change="alterProperty('name')">  
 </text-input>
 <text-input
   @change="alterProperty('email')">  
 </text-input>
```

My `Parent` would have this method:

```
alterProperty (property) {
  return (changeValue) => {
    this.info[property] = changeValue
  }
}
```

So far, nothing, I can't get this to work, maybe something in the way Vue handle things, I don't know. If anyone know something about that, I appreciate the help.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check this jsFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/2mmbsyy3/

It works precisely as you expect. Here is how I am using the `text-input` component:

```html
<text-input :value="userInfo.name" @change="alterProperty('name', $event)"></text-input>
```

**Note:** `alterProperty` is an **inline method** that is directly called in the `@change` event handler. So it will not get the default `$event` parameter - the special variable that carries the arguments from child component, unless you include it. In your code, this is the missing part.

Ref: https://vuejs.org/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers

In the sample jsFiddle implementation, the `$event` is only the event arguments from child component, not a DOM `event`. My alterProperty method (in parent component) works as follows:

```js
alterProperty: function(propToChange, newValue) {
    this.userInfo[propToChange] = newValue;
}
```

The jsFiddle also outputs the object on parent component, which gets modified as expected.

**Edit: Additional Notes**

Your child component should not bind `this.value` directly to your `input` element, as `this.value` is passed via props. If you try to do that, you will get a console error messsage like:

> *[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly...*

To avoid that, I have used a local computed property - `textFieldValue`, which has its getter and setter methods. While getter simply returns `this.value`, the setter is the one that sends the `change` event back to parent component, without touching `this.value` that is passed via props.

Comment: this `$event` will do the trick, didn't knew about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have write 2 fiddle to archive the effective. One way is to use v-on, emitter, to archive communicate between child and parent component. One way is directly update parent data in child component.

I recommend first way.

Check the first one, use v-on, emitter way, https://jsfiddle.net/seaify/p8fh108j/

```
Vue.component('text-input', {
    props: ["parent_field"],
    template: `
        <input type="text" v-model="text">
    `,
    data: function() {
      return {text: ''}
    },
    watch: {
       text: function(value, old_value) {
          this.$emit('update_parent', this.parent_field, value)
       }
    }
});

Vue.component('my-app-form', {
    template: `
        <div class="my-app-form">
            <div class="my-text-input">
                Name: <text-input parent_field="name" v-on:update_parent='update_self'></text-input>
            </div>
            <div class="my-text-input">
                Email: <text-input parent_field="email" v-on:update_parent='update_self'></text-input>
            </div>
            <div class="result">Result: name = {{name}}, email = {{email}}</div>
        </div>

        `,
    methods: {
       update_self: function(key, value) {
       this[key] = value
      }
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
                name: "",
                email: ""          
        }
    },
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: `
        <div>
            <my-app-form></my-app-form>
        </div>
    `,
});
```

Check this fiddle example, directly update parent component, without communication, https://jsfiddle.net/seaify/jczowb54/10

```
Vue.component('text-input', {
    props: ["parent_field"],
    template: `
        <input type="text" v-model="text">
    `,
    data: function() {
      return {text: ''}
    },
    watch: {
       text: function(value, old_value) {
            this.$parent[this.parent_field] = value
       }
    }
});

Vue.component('my-app-form', {
    template: `
        <div class="my-app-form">
            <div class="my-text-input">
                Name: <text-input parent_field="name"></text-input>
            </div>
            <div class="my-text-input">
                Email: <text-input parent_field="email" ></text-input>
            </div>
            <div class="result">Result: name = {{name}}, email = {{email}}</div>
        </div>

        `,
    data: function() {
        return {
                name: "",
                email: ""          
        }
    },
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: `
        <div>
            <my-app-form></my-app-form>
        </div>
    `
});
```

Thanks to Mani, i have fork your fiddle and update the code.

Comment: Even if that works, it's not the right way to do it. Check Mani's answer. The point is to use the events to handle in any component with a proper API between any parent/child communication. Thank you for answering though

Comment: @cassioscabral i have update the post, add emitter, event way fiddler. Actually it's essentially same way, when compared to Mani's answer. But my code's readability is better.

Comment: @cassioscabral As to the second fiddler, directly update the component, i think it  depends on how we think and choose. It actually have no side effect and code is less.