# Passing in two-way binding prop to a slot

Tags: vue.js

I'm somewhat new to Vue, and I'm having particular difficulty in passing in `formData` to my individual child nodes. Ideally each child node simply updates the parent `formData` object allowing me to submit the form data later on as a whole.

I've setup a JSFiddle to illustrate: https://jsfiddle.net/3nm1mrLo/

My current thinking is that I should `v-bind:field="formData.name"` but that throws an error. It seems as though `formData` doesn't exist in the slot based HTML.

Any pointers would be gratefully received. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As you rightly said, you need to use `v-bind:field="formData.name"` or `:field="formData.name"`.

It is not working because you have defined the main app template directly in your html, and used "content distribution" to include `<example-form>` and `<example-input>`.

As defined in the docs, this content-distribution (or "transclusion" if you are familiar with Angular 1.x) works fine, but the scope belongs to the main app (the root instance, because the template belongs to it).

Ref: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Compilation-Scope

Quote:

> A simple rule of thumb for component scope is:
>
> *Everything in the parent template is compiled in parent scope; everything in the child template is compiled in child scope.*

If you are curious, try changing your main app (root instance) as follows:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '*[my-app]',
    data: function() {
        return {
            formData: { name: 'abc', location: 'xyz'}
        };
    }
});
```

Now you will see that formData is not `undefined` anymore.

But a more proper method is to include `<example-input>` as part of the template of `example-form` component as follows:

```js
Vue.component('example-form', {
    template: `
        <div class="my-example-form">
            <form><pre>{{formData}}</pre><slot></slot></form>
            <example-input :field="formData.name"></example-input>
            <example-input :field="formData.location"></example-input>
        </div>
    `,
    data: function() {
        return {
            formData: { name: '', location: ''}
        };
    }
});
```

Now it will bind to the right `formData` as you would expect.

But this will still not work for you because `props` is a one-way binding only. The child component (`example-input`) will get the value, but will not pass the data changes back to parent component (`example-form`)

For child to pass data back to parent, the right way is to use `$emit` as explained in this question: [Updating parent data via child component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349648/updating-parent-data-via-child-component)

If you want to have an `<example-input>` component to work as form elements, here is a related answer which works like what you expect: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40337942/654825 - there is a working jsFiddle also.

Comment: Thanks!

My problem was due to the misunderstanding of the root component. I was mistakenly thinking that the first component `example-form` was the root, when in fact it's the node you initialise Vue on.

It all makes perfect sense now.